# Does the Rigol DS1054Z have a "integrated 2 channel waveform generator"?

Tags: oscilloscope, waveform

I'm seeing that this device lists, [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012938E76), as having

> "and integrated 2 channel waveform generator"

Does it have a waveform generator? And, if so what is the difference between a waveform generator as supplied by this device, and one that an external device can supply like the [Rigol DG4062](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007C8GL2O) which is also a 2 channel wave form generator?

Comment: I think you're having trouble reading Amazon listings. It doesn't say that, in fact the Q&A section says it doesn't. Other more expensive scopes in that series do. The question is somewhat O/T for this board anyway.

Comment: The DS1054Z isn't available with an arbitrary waveform generator. I think the cheapest model that has it is the DS1074-S which is $750 USD.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: @user44635 it's right under "product description"

Comment: I wanted to compare the specs of the integrated and the external frequency generator to point out some important differences but they are behind a registration wall. -1 for Rigol.

Comment: @Arsenal I was going to make that my next question actually. I'd be curious to know the advantages of buying an oscilliscope like the DS1074Z-S ($695) vs the DS1054Z ($400) + their entry level waveform generator DG1022 ($400), because we're only talking about a $100 difference.

Comment: I am always a fan of specialized pieces. If you arfe going for entry level things, just go with the simpler cheaper one so you can learn what you like and don't like. Then get a cheap generator later. Work into the more specialized equipment later.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, only the [DS1074Z-S has the waveform generator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXPRL46).

You can find the same bad verbiage in [Amazon's listing on the DS1074Z too](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXPOE6O),

> The DS1000Z Series is the new economic level Digital Oscilloscope from Rigol to meet the customer's applications with its innovative technology, industry leading specifications, powerful trigger functions and broad analysis capabilities. The DS1000Z 4 channel oscilloscopes come in 70 or 100 MHz versions with a 7 inch display and Rigol's UltraVision technology as well as a host of options. Add the optional analysis, decoding, deep memory, and **integrated 2 channel waveform generator** for a powerful 4 channel scope at an exceptional price.

That verbiage seems to be copied from [the Rigol site on the ds1000z series which is in itself wrong](http://www.rigolna.com/products/digital-oscilloscopes/ds1000z/). However the ds1000z series includes DS1054z, DS1074Z, DS1074Z-S, DS1104Z and the DS1104Z-S. With only the `-S` models, (the DS1054Z-S and DS1074Z-S) having `Built in 2 channels 25MHz waveform Generator(DS1000Z-S)` listed under their features.

Comment: You should have highlighted the word **optional** in that sentence.

Comment: It's not optional. It's only available in one model. Where as the rest of that crap can be turned on with a [software upgrade.](http://gotroot.ca/rigol/riglol/)